# xlwings ToPosixPath = MacScript(s) runtime error

Tags: python, xlwings

I am relatively new to programming and am trying to call Python from Excel using xlwings. I am using Python 2.7.10, Excel 14.5.2.

Following the example given in xlwings documentation, I import xlwings.bas and use the basic example:

```
Sub MyMacro()

    RunPython ("import mymodule; mymodule.rand_numbers()")

End Sub
```

With mymodule at pwd on terminal. When I run this macro, I get a runtime error ("5"), which points me to the line `ToPosixPath = MacScript(s)` in the `xlwings.bas` file.

Would sincerely appreciate any help from this forum in resolving this problem.

Comment: Click on `Debug` so you get to the VBA Editor, then open `View > Immediate Window` and write `?s` and hit `Enter`- what's the value of s?

Comment: Thanks! Following these instructions I get:

?s
tell application "Finder"
POSIX path of ""
end tell

Comment: Try to download the fibonacci sample zipfile from the homepage and check if you get the same error when running that one.

Comment: I do not get a similar error when using the Fibonacci sequence

Comment: Ok I think I see what's going on (will post a real answer when you confirm): did you change the `PYTHONPATH` in the VBA module to `""`?

Comment: I left all as it was when installed. Currently this reads: 
PYTHON_MAC = ""
PYTHONPATH = ThisWorkbook.Path

Comment: Umm OK, then I can't tell what's happening but advise you to work off the sample you downloaded. Anyway, there *was* actually a little bug, now logged [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/250)

Comment: Thanks Felix! I will work off the dl sample (seems to work if I put all modules in the same folder where things are unzipped).